# React Netlify form does not submit

Tags: reactjs, forms, netlify

Im making a personal website for training and I wanted to use Netlify form submission for `/contact` URL I tried adding just `netlify` , `netlify='true'`, and other things like that but i just gives me 404 error everytime im trying to use Netlify form submission, but it doesnt seem to work no matter what I do, I followed several tutorials and repos but still does not work. It just gives 404 error and other stuff;
and please check my github repo,

*[My GitHub Repo's Link](https://github.com/sbayrak/suatbayrak-portfolio-master)*
and here is my `Contact.js` component;

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
const encode = (data) => {
  return Object.keys(data)
    .map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' +         encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
.join('&');
};
const Contact = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch('/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
      body: encode({
        'form-name': 'contact',
          name: name,
           email: email,
          text: text,
          }),
        })
        .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
     .catch((error) => alert(error));

     e.preventDefault();
    };
 return (
   <Fragment>
  <div className='contact'>
    <div className='contact-wrapper'>
      <div className='title'>
        <span>Contact me</span>
      </div>
      <div className='contact-form'>
        <form
          className='myform'
          method='POST'
          name='contact'
          data-netlify='true'
          onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
        >
          <input type='hidden' name='form-name' value='contact'></input>

          <input
            type='text'
            placeholder='Your Name'
            name='name'
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
          <input
            type='email'
            placeholder='Your E-Mail'
            name='email'
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          ></input>
          <textarea
            placeholder='Your message'
            name='message'
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
          <button type='submit'>Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
     </div>
   </Fragment>
   );
};

export default Contact;
```

[image: log]

Answer (score 1):

Netlify's forms work by their servers editing your html at deploy to add in their hooks for submitting the form.

With a React app, the form will not be visible in the html at deploy, so this won't work.

Netlify have a guide for how to set up their forms with SPAs, view it here: https://www.netlify.com/blog/2017/07/20/how-to-integrate-netlifys-form-handling-in-a-react-app/

Comment: I figured this out after a long research, I just added a static form to my `public/index.html` and it worked! now im trying to implement recaptcha, but thank you for answering my question